# How to access root from subdomain

Tags: html, .htaccess, web

Let's say I've got my ErrorDocuments in my root folder (files).

```
files
|
|----- .htaccess
|
|----- index.html
|
|----- 404.html
|
|----- 403.html
|
|----- ...
|
|
|----- abc ----- index.html
        |
        |------- .htaccess
```

My files/.htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 401 /401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
```

My provider does automatically link `domain.com/abc` to `abc.domain.com`.
But if I get a error on my subdomain my `404.html` doesn't show up because the webroot for `abc.domain.com` is `domain.com/abc` and not `domain.com`.

How can I configure my webspace so I can access my root without hardcoding my domain.

Comment: Maybe via .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .htaccess should look like this:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^403.html*$ domain.com/403.html
RewriteRule ^404.html*$ domain.com/404.html
RewriteRule ^405.html*$ domain.com/405.html
RewriteRule ^500.html*$ domain.com/500.html`
```